# Android N: how to dynamically enable/disable TileService

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

I am trying to enable/disable a TileService at runtime and I have no idea how to do it.
I have a TileService that performs actions which rely on the availability on the device of GooglePlayServices.
If I start my application, I can enable or disable the TileService by calling

```
getPackageManager()
    .setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName
    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED
    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

and everything is just fine. What I am trying to do is to understand how to be able to enable or disable the TileService without having to start the application.
I don't understand how I can detect when the user pulls down the quick settings and hit the edit button, which is where I should be able to dynamically enable or disable the TileService. I can't find any method in the TileService class.

Answer (score 1):

> how I can detect when the user pulls down the quick settings and hit the edit button

That is not supported, and that is too late for what you want to do ("which is where I should be able to dynamically enable or disable the TileService").

Have `android:enabled="false"` on the `<service>` in the manifest. Enable it through `setComponentEnabledSetting()` on first run of your app, after you have confirmed that Play Services is available.

Comment: Thank you, I was really trying to avoid any workaround and find a way to not have the user launch the app, but I guess there is no way. Thank you